# Install the same operating system on mutiple servers

Tags: server, system

I am looking for a solution that let me install ubuntu in a modular way on mutiple server . In other words does any solution let me install one ubuntu server on multiple coputers so that the same Opearting system can control multiple computers.

Comment: how do you mean 'the same OS'? do you want to have it insalled on just one (network) drive that multiple machines can boot from? because the 'system' will (and must!) not be the same. there are things that are dynamically set (`/proc`, `/dev`) and booting from the same source may mess up your random number generator and therefore the security of session keys that are generated while the servers are running.

Comment: I want that my servers share these directories. even /proc /dev /etc .... an operating system that is accessible from the network by all the cluster servers. where the servers must access and modify the same directories.

Comment: i do not think `/proc` (`/dev` and `/sys`) can be shared.  they do not exist on the disk and are dynamically generated at boot time. - may i ask what your goal is?

Comment: Ok so  directories `/var`  `/etc`  can be shared or not. and how can i share them between servers

Comment: also `/var` may not be a good idea; you do not want 2 machines writing to e.g. `/var/log/syslog` at the same time. but `/bin`, `/etc` and others may work. on a network drive for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

You can also check this page, in the section "Server and network installations"
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD

Comment: Thx for your answer . Actually, what i mean by install on multiple servers is that I have one OS fo two machines for example. In other words, the OS should be running on the two machines at the same time. what you shared in your answer is realted to the PXE Boot.

Comment: So, if i understand well, you want to make the server a server (je), and the other two machines clients that connect to the server with an account and use the machine like a terminal?

Comment: No it's not that way. I want that the operating system kernel is reparted between my cluster's machines. So i can use from the machine that i want.

Comment: Ive never seen that, but everything is possible. Lets see if some expert know. Sorry i could not help you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a Master Server running [XDMCP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjABahUKEwiipvSx3aHIAhWEmYAKHUFrBaQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntu.com%2Fxdmcp&usg=AFQjCNESobYQnjB9AdBeuye1sM__sxoX4Q), and several clients that run XDMCP clients.  These clients will log into the Master Server and all operations/files/everything will be on the Master Server.

You probably will want to install Ubuntu Desktop on the Server, or Ubuntu Server with a GUI package and a XDMCP server.  The clients can run Ubuntu Desktop, or even Windows or Mac OS.